# Jquery limit accepted characters by place in string

Tags: jquery, regex, text, field

I'm basically trying to force a field to only accept a specific string format.

```
$jq('input#id').bind('keyup', function(){
var sanitized = $jq(this).val().replace(/[^0-9a-z]/g,'');
$jq(this).val('WO'+sanitized);
```

In this current example I'm forcing the first characters to be `WO` and then adding on valid characters (valid being numbers/letters).

Building on this idea, I'm wondering if there would be a way to do the following:
Force the first 5 digits to be only numbers and the last 5 digits to be only letters?

Comment: Why do you think you are forcing *the first* characters to be *WC*? You are removing all non digits and lowercase letters. Then, you append this to a `WO`.

Comment: Explain "Forcing"... What do you want to happen when the value isn't what you want it to be?

Comment: @stribizhev I apologize, I meant WO. The idea there was just to append alpha-numeric characters after those specific letters.

Comment: @Amit I was thinking just displaying a simple error/prompt or clearing the field would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach...

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var caret = $(this).caret();
    // var caret = this.selectionStart;  // Not supported in IE <= 8 (but who cares...)
    if((caret < 5 && !/^\d$/.test(char)) ||
       (caret >= 5 && !/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(char))) {e.preventDefault()}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apache.hvitahusid.is/jslib/jquery.caret-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: This works very well.
I also like that it doesn't accept the unwanted characters at all - simplifies the errors.

Comment: No. What version is currently being used? And what are the browser requirements for the webpage? You might consider updating.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex to check if the first 5 characters are digits, and the last five ones are English letters, you can use a simple regex:

```
var re = /^\d{5}.*[a-zA-Z]{5}$/;
```

The `^` will make sure we start checking at the beginning of the string, `\d{5}` matches 5 digits, `.*` matches anything but newline symbols, and `[a-zA-Z]{5}` matches exactly 5 English letters before the end of string `$`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX0tR8/1)

```js
var sanitized = "12345some textqwert";
if (sanitized.match(/^\d{5}.*[a-zA-Z]{5}$/))
  alert("Valid");
else
  alert("Invalid");

sanitized = "1234some textqwert";
if (sanitized.match(/^\d{5}.*[a-zA-Z]{5}$/))
  alert("Valid");
else
  alert("Invalid");
```

Comment: I'm still playing with this as well - both answers point out the syntax I was curious about.  Thank you!